# Parallel.ForEach doesn't return after loopResult.Stop()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

This is what my loop looks like:

```
var loopResult = Parallel.ForEach(folder.Items.Cast<object>(), (item, loopState) =>
    {
        if (!loadData)
        {
            loopState.Stop();
            return;
        }

        DoSomeWork(item);
    }
);

if (loopResult.IsCompleted)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("done");
}
```

The problem is the code never gets to `if (loopResult.IsCompleted)`. After executing `return;` for all the different threads, absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: What is happening inside `DoSomeWork`?

Comment: that is actually the right question to ask, it got stuck in that method trying to Invoke a method call on GUI thread, which never returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code never gets to the body of `if (loopResult.IsCompleted)` because the parallel loop has been stopped successfully. You can check it as follows:

```
/* ForEach loop as above */

if (!loopResult.IsCompleted && 
         !loopResult.LowestBreakIteration.HasValue)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Loop was stopped");
}

if (loopResult.IsCompleted)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Loop was done without stopping");
}
```

You can find useful information how to `Stop/Break` a parallel loop in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx), starting from *Breaking Out of Loops Early* subsection.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopresult.aspx), `IsCompleted` will not return true if a loop was ended prematurely:

> Gets whether the loop ran to completion, such that all iterations of the loop were executed and the loop didn't receive a request to end prematurely.

Your call to `Stop()` causes all other loops to [exit early](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop.aspx), resulting in `IsCompleted` evaluating to false.